# Getting Domain Usage using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, domains

Using this code I am able to list all domains inside my GDB

```
import arcpy
ws = "C:\\data\\water.gdb"
domains = arcpy.da.ListDomains(ws)
for domain in domains:
    print('Domain name: {0}'.format(domain.name))
```

How can I list the domain usage for each of these domains?

Comment: What do you mean by "domain usage"?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean a list of feature class and/or table fields that are constrained by each domain?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this code to determine what domain is used by what field in a feature class.

```
import arcpy
ws = "C:\\data\\water.gdb"
arcpy.env.workspace = ws
domains = arcpy.da.ListDomains(ws)
# get the feature datasets
datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type = 'Feature')
# append the top level dataset
datasets = [''] + datasets if datasets is not None else []

for domain in domains:
    for fd in datasets:
        # get the feature classes
        fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=fd)
        for fc in fcs:
            fields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
            for field in fields:
                if field.domain == domain:
                    print('Found field ' + field.name + ' in feature class ' + fc + ' using ' + domain)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import arcpy
ws = r'C:\\data\\water.gdb'
domains = arcpy.da.ListDomains(ws)
for domain in domains:
    print('Domain name: {0}'.format(domain.name))
```